# Do USB 1.1 and 2.0 on the same hub force all devices to 1.1?

Tags: usb

I have a USB 1.1 keyboard and a USB 2.0 flash drive. Will the keyboard slow down other USB 2.0 devices connected to a USB 2.0 hub to 1.1 speeds?

Assume that the computer port for the hub is also USB 2.0. I understand that the hub will share the existing bandwidth and not multiply it.

My question is very similar to this but I'm interested in 2.0 and 1.1. [Does a USB 2.0 device connected to a USB 3.0 hub slow down the hub to 2.0 speeds?](https://superuser.com/questions/477241/does-a-usb-2-0-device-connected-to-a-usb-3-0-hub-slow-down-the-hub-to-2-0-speeds)

I ask because a quick google [produced this](http://arstechnica.co.uk/civis/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=100554) but it is quite old. If things are as described here, is the situation any better with a USB 3.0 hub and 1.1 and 2.0 devices?

Comment: Your google results are accurate, it being old, does not make it inaccurate.  USB 1.1 is old so information on it will be old.  The question you linked to also applies.

Comment: No is the short answer.

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug in Linux, but as soon as I plug in my mouse (1.5M speed) on the same hub than my external sound device, firefox complains that the external sound card has "insufficient bandwidth" and sound stops working. So for me some variation of this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a fairly standard 2.0 hub, it will not slow down, the USB 1.1 peripherals will run at 1.1 speeds, and 2.0 peripherals will run at 2.0 speeds, assuming the hub is connected to a USB 2.0 port.

Same hold for USB 3.0, mixing USB devices (1.1/2.0/3.0) on a hub will not slow down the overall connection or a specific device provided the hub is doing it's job correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can determine the speed a USB bus is running at by

**Windows**

As explained in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/388246/172195) by [Synetech](https://superuser.com/users/3279/synetech) you can use the [USBView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560019(v=vs.85).aspx) tool from Microsoft that comes on the installation CD or as part of the Microsoft Debugger Tools.

**Mac OS X**

For the Mac you'll use the use *System Information* or *System Profiler* and select USB from the left column as explained in [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202875) support article from Apple

**Linux**

On Linux you'll need to execute `lsusb -v` as explained in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2087/70158) from [maxschlepzig](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1131/maxschlepzig) over at Unix.se